# Problems with Glob

Tags: php, glob, opendir

I am using Glob to get the name of a file in a directory. There is always only 1 file in the directory.

But I have a CMS, so my path is sometimes different, and I can't use my `BASE_URL` or full url, because then I got this notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0.

I am using this code:

```
$files = glob('<?php echo BASE_URL?>images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE); 
print_r($files[0])
```

It works good on the home url when I leave `<?php echo BASE_URL?>`.

Someone with a fix or knows another way?

Comment: Your error means that your array empty is and you should use `printr_($files)` instead of `print_r($files[0])`. Than it will display the full array and an empty array if the `glob()` function found nothing.

Comment: You cannot use `glob()` on an URL, it has to be a file system access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the BASE_URL more directly, your text will actually include the `<?php echo BASE_URL?>` as part of the string.

```
$files = glob(BASE_URL.'images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

But you probably want to use `ROOT_PATH` instead, something which will be a file path on the server.  Or something like

```
 $files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Still the notice; Notice: Undefined offset: 0. How to use ROOT_PATH with this?

Comment: @Danny if `ROOT_PATH` is what your CMS says is the web root of your install then that is what you want... just sub it in for `BASE_URL`. And then make any modifications to the path from there.

Comment: Also $files = glob(ROOT_PATH.'images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE); not working when I define ROOT_PATH. Maybe because I am on localhost?

Comment: I've added an alternative version using 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' - note that there is a '/' before the image directory.

Comment: What CMS are you using @Danny?

Comment: I am making my own CMS @prodigitalson

Comment: The main thing is to check what the path results in and does it point to the files your after.

Comment: Oh.. in that case you should define a constant for yourself that maps to the install root of your CMS... this may or may not always be the same as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: I defined BASE_URL to the root of my CMS. But that doesnt work. @NigelRen, your other wat is also not working :( Still the same notice.

Comment: Where is the 'images' directory?

Comment: root/images/logo

Comment: And is this in your document root?  If so try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root/images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}'`

Comment: Not working. Notice: Undefined offset: 0. Only when I use this, it works: $files = glob('images/logo/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
 print_r($files[0])

Comment: In your configuration file, you need to set a value which is the root of your content.  This will then for the path you use in various files.  Without having your directory structure I can't say what you need to set it to.  All I can say is this is how you should use it when you sort it out.

Comment: define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost/sitecms/");

the map for the image which name I need:
localhost/sitecms/images/logo

What I want: I want to get the name of the file in "Logo" on every page, for example: localhost/sitecms/images/logo/NameOfFile.png/jpg

Comment: The problem is that BASE_URL is a URL - and as pointed out, this won't work with `glob()`.  You need something which is (for example) '/var/www/html/sitecms' which is the root of the content on the host systems file system

Comment: Maybe I make it to difficult. Can I rename the file on opload?